# RemoveEventListener is not working when adding an EventListener inside another

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do my own color picker wheel with Javascript, where I want to be able to select a color by dragging a small circle (with an "+" symbol inside it) inside the wheel or by clicking somewhere on the wheel (without dragging the small circle, but then the small circle has to go to that position). Also I want to be able to drag the small circle after I have pressed somewhere on the wheel (when mousedown event is triggered) until I release the mouse button (mouseup).

HERE: It is much easier to see here what I want visually:
    https://jsfiddle.net/s1qesLp9/1/

If you uncomment row 78, then you can see what the problem is.

The problem is that when I am working with add and remove eventListeners (since I want to do the all above, I use mousedown,mousemove and mouseup) I get so that the number of alerts is increased by 1 for every mousedown on the wheel (I only want one alert here, independent on how many mousedowns on the wheel!). I was thinking if it has to do with the document object or if there is something wrong with removing the eventListeners, but I am not sure.

Here comes the part that I have problem with:

```
document.getElementById('wheel').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    targetMove(e);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
      document.onmouseup = null;
      alert("Here is the problem: For every mousedown on the wheel, the 
      number of alerts is increased by 1 (I only want one alert here!)");
    });
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!

Instead of having this:

```
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
    document.onmouseup = null;
    alert("Here is the problem: For every mousedown on the wheel, the number 
of alerts is increased by 1 (I only want one alert here!)");
});
```

I have this:

```
document.onmouseup = function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
    document.onmouseup = null;
    alert("Problem is solved");
};
```

So the problem was to use the method addEventListener on mouseup and is replaced by giving a function to the document.onmouseup instead.

Thanks for trying to help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're adding a new listener to mouseup after every mousedown and never removing it.  You can move that do a named function and call a remove before adding it.  Removing a listener that doesn't exist doesn't cause any problems that I'm aware of.

<--edit-->I should have mentioned this would probably be easier from a logic standpoint if you set flags for each action.  So on mousedown you would move target and set mouseheld to true.  Then on mousemove, if mouseheld move the target.  Finally onmouseup, set mouseheld to false.<--edit--/>

```js
document.getElementById('wheel').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    targetMove(e);
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
    
    //This listener is getting added with every mousedown and is never removed
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
      document.onmouseup = null;
      alert("Here is the problem: For every mousedown on the wheel, the 
      number of alerts is increased by 1 (I only want one alert here!)");
    });
}, false);
```

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by setting flags. Is it possible to show with code too, because then it is easier to understand. Feel free to change the code in the provided code :) You said that I never never remove the listener to mouseup, do I not remove the listener (mouseup and mousemove) by following code inside function():                                                               
      document.removeEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
      document.onmouseup = null;

Comment: As far as I am concerned removing listeners can be done by: document.onmouseup = null OR document.removeEventListener('mouseup', targetMove). I have tried both without any solution for everything to work as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Your event listener for the `mousedown` event, is adding the same event listeners again on each `mousedown`.  If you remove those event listeners from the callback function, and add them separately, you won't have this problem.

```
document.getElementById('wheel').addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    targetMove(e);  
}, false);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', targetMove);
    document.onmouseup = null;
    alert("Problem solved!  You are binding this event listener only once.");
  });
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvfs0df5/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! The problem of doing that is that there are some functionalities that disappears. As you can see on the link provided above you can click somewhere on the wheel and drag the small circle, but also drag the small circle after you have pressed somewhere on the wheel until you release the mouse button.

Comment: Yes, I will only get one alert with your solution, but I also want to have all functionalities with the small circle (the only functionality with your code that you cannot do is to drag the small circle after you have pressed somewhere on the wheel (without draging the small circle at the beginning) and when the mouse button is released, then the small circle stays there). If you compare my link with yours, then you will notice what I mean.